# How do I specify an existing docker-compose.yml file in my devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

I have an existing project with a docker-compose.yml file that runs a zookeeper and kafka image. How do I specify that the docker-compose.yml file needs to be loaded in my devcontainer.json?

Would it be possible to not modify the docker-compose file since others are using the same file, but not using VS Code. The docker-compose.yml looks like this.

```
---
version: '1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      xxxxx
    expose:
     xxxxx
     
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
        xxxxx
    expose:
      xxxxx
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `"dockerComposeFile": "./path/to/docker-compose.yml",` the container you enter into should not exit, adding `command: sleep infinity` to compose is the fix

Comment: oh your need add `"shutdownAction": "stopCompose",` too

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Lawrence. <br/>

My .devcontain.json looks like this:<br/>

`
{
 "name": "setup_sys",
 "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
 "postCreateCommand": "sleep infinity",
 "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
}
`
<br/>
The docker-compose.yml is in the same folder. When I try loading it in a container, I get the following

```
Service 'undefined' configured in devcontainer.json not found in Docker Compose configuration.
```

Comment: add `"service": "zookeeper",` or whichever one you want to enter into

Comment: Do I need to create multiple "service" keys? One for each service in the docker-compose.yml? And do I need to add also the command sleep infinity, under what key would I add that? I presumed postCreateCommand, but not sure

Comment: vs-code only enters into the one container, yeah you want to prevent the container stopping. - my use case is mount the app/development/codebase and compose in the other services

Comment: So, I can start all the containers and add a ubuntu image so that I can enter that. 

But I need all of them to not stop right? So, do I do the sleep infinity command for each of the containers? How do I specify that I want that command executed on each of the containers?

Thanks again!

Comment: that should really be in/part of the `docker-compose.yml` with other options. `.devcontainer.json` is for mounting the editor into a specific container